# Why is ${n \choose k} = {n \choose n-k}$?

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, binomial-coefficients

I noticed an interesting behavior with the binomial coefficient I find intuitive but can't yet to prove myself.

Why is ${n \choose k} = {n \choose n-k}$?

It seems intuitive due to the way the formula is written:

$${n \choose k}=\frac{n!}{(n−k)!k!}$$

and the fact is it is used to calculate the the binomial probability mass function so that ${n \choose k}$ is equal for both $n (\text{success})$ and $n-k (\text{failure})$ (again only for binomial probability of either success or failure and not other option to count for)..

So ${5 \choose 3} = {5 \choose 2}= 10$
and $ {10\choose  6} = {10 \choose 4} = 210 $

Can anyone help with proving this generally?

Comment: You have the formula. You even say the formula makes it seem intuitive. What's stopping you from using it to complete the proof?

Comment: Observe by commutativity of multiplication that ${n \choose k}=\frac{n!}{(n−k)!k!} = \frac{n!}{k!(n−k)!} =\frac{n!}{(n - (n - k))!(n−k)!}  = {n \choose {n - k}} $.

Comment: I have tried the following but got it wrong I afraid:
/frac{n!}{(n−k)!k!} = /frac{n!}{(n−(n-k))!(n-k)!} = /frac{n!}{(n+n-k))!(n-k)!} = /frac{n!}{(2n-k))!(n-k)!} ??

Comment: @TomerVagenfeld $n-(n-k)=n-n+k=k$

Comment: @user2628206: I don't think phrases like "commutativity of multiplication" help at all at this level.

Comment: $n-(n-k) = k$, not $2n - k$. You have incorrectly applied the distributive law of multiplication over addition.

Comment: @TonyK Good point

Comment: Thank you very much @user2628206

Answer (score 1):

Clearly algebraically: $$\binom{n}{n-k}=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!(n-(n-k))!}=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}=\binom nk$$

and combinatorically: suppose you have $n$ objects on a table and move $k$ into a box, leaving $n-k$ on the table. Every arrangement of $k$ objects in the box corresponds to exactly one arrangement of $n-k$ objects left on the table.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a set $A$ with $n$ elements, then $\binom{n}{k}$ counts the number of subsets of size $k$.  You can pair each subset with its complement.  So each subset of size $k$ can be paired (in a one-to-one way) with a subset of size $n-k$.

So $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$ $\ldots$ I think.

Answer (score 0):

I’m a little confused about what you’re asking. You can prove it easily using the formula and just comparing. If you want an explanation or some more intuition, think about picking items. For example picking 6 items from 10, leaves 4 items which are also in a way ”picked”. So picking 6 items is the same as picking 4 items.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the algebraic equality you mentioned and then work through the cancellations using algebra and the properties of factorials. However, I don't think of this as "intuitive."  My favorite explanation of the identity is still the following: $\binom{n}{k}$ is the number of ways of choosing $k$ things from $n$ objects (without the order mattering). But we can do this two ways, either by directly picking out the $k$ things that we want (like a very focused child), in which case the number of ways is $\binom{n}{k}$, or we could pick what we want simply by choosing what we *don't* want, putting them aside, and then choosing the rest (like a very picky child). So we choose the $n - k$ things we don't want and then select the remaining $k$ things, but the number of ways of picking $n-k$ things from $n$ things is $\binom{n}{n-k}$. Because in the end we are left with the same $k$ objects being selected, then we must have $\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{n-k}$.